# How get use Google News API or extract information?

Tags: google-api, google-news

I'm working on a widget where we pull info from Google news.

I know how to get a publisher ID number, for example, CNN's ID is 669475.  However, how do pull information about a specific publisher from their ID number?  For example, how would I find their official name and their domain?

I can't find any documentation on this whatsoever.  I don't need a ton of information, really just the name of the news station and their domain.

Answer (score 1):

> The Google News Search API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011.[...]

From https://developers.google.com/news-search/